# Increase GraphViz text editor font size Windows

Tags: graphviz

Is there a way to increase size and typeface of the text editor font in GraphViz?  The default font is too small for easy editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but keep reading!  This very old feature request

> Submitted by erg on Tue, 12/27/2011 - 16:05.
>   Gvedit can, in principle, support any font, but at present, there is no mechanism by which the user can set this.

suggests that there is no way, but **even so, I have found a useful workaround that I use daily whenever I have to interact with the GraphViz editor.**

If I paste just a bit of text from Microsoft Word (for example) in a larger font, the control in GraphViz honors that.  Then I can continue to type in that font.  Example:

[image]

I speculate that this works because the "text control" in GraphViz honors Rich Text Format.  Anyway, this is how I make the font large enough to be usable.  Simply paste in some text from any word processor in a font of your choosing, then keep typing.  Hope this works for you, I do it all the time.  My eyes are too old for that default font.  ;)

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of that and I was wondering if there is another way.